# comparing unsorted numbers in two files

Tags: python

I have two files and I'm trying to compare two files that contain numbers.

```
File1:
123
456
789

File2:
234
567
890
34342
```

I ran into two problems that I don't know how to solve.
This is my code:

```
import filecmp

file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')

file1Lines = file1.readlines()
file2Lines = file2.readlines()

matchedList = []
unmatchedList = []

for line in file1Lines:
    for secline in file2Lines:
        if line == secline:
            matchedList.append(line)
        else:
            unmatchedList.append(line)

file1.close()
file2.close()

print(unmatchedList)
```

I'm trying to iterate on the lines in both files, and put the matching numbers (only one copy of it) in the matchedList and what not matched to put in the unmatchedlist.
I thought about Iterating over the file2Lines for each line in the file1Lines (this shouldn't be a problem as the files are relativly small), the problem is that whenever the lines does not match, it just appends 'line' in the unmatched array.
This is what I get in the end:

```
['123\n', '123\n', '123\n', '123\n', '456\n', '456\n', '456\n', '456\n', '789\n', '789\n', '789\n', '789\n']
```

another problem I have is that if one of the files is longer (like file2) it won't check that, and I won't know if the number matched or not.

Comment: If you're already reading all lines to variables, why not do it in 1 mathcing loop? Your problem is not well defined. Do you want ot compare each line in one file to all other lines in the other file? Or match first line in file1 to first line in file2, second line to second line and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job crafted for `set` data structure.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

```py
file1_contents = '''123
456
789'''
file2_contents = '''234
567
123
456
456
234
123
876
890
34342'''

file1 = set(file1_contents.splitlines())
file2 = set(file2_contents.splitlines())

# intersection to find common lines
common = file1 & file2
# symmetric difference for finding uncommon lines
# all lines = file1 + file2
# all lines - common = (lines in 1 but not in 2) + (lines in 2 but not in 1)
uncommon = file1 ^ file2

print('common', common)
print('uncommon', uncommon)
```

output:

```
common {'123', '456'}
uncommon {'789', '34342', '876', '890', '234', '567'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't use Python at all, but I needed this script written in Python so I got stuck with it. You helped me alot! thanks!